# If $\dim\ker(A)=1$ then $\dim\ker(A^{k+1})-\dim\ker(A^{k})\leq 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the fact that, if $\dim\ker(A)=1$ then $\dim\ker(A^{k+1})-\dim\ker(A^{k})\leq 1$.

I found a proof with induction on $k$. It's not extremely complicated, but still, I have the impression that there is a more straightforward way to prove this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ker A^k\subseteq\ker A^{k+1}$, so we can take a basis $\left\{v_1,\dots,v_m\right\}$ of $\ker A^k$ and complete it to $B=\left\{v_1,\dots,v_m,w_1,\dots,w_r\right\}$ of $\ker A^{k+1}$.

Suppose on the contrary that $r>1$. Now $\left\{A^kw_1,\dots,A^kw_r\right\}\subseteq\ker A$. Explain why $A^kw_1$ spans the others, and then show that $\alpha_jw_j-w_1\in\ker A^k$ for all $j=2,\dots,r$, hence $B$ is linearly dependent, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$\ker(AB)=B^{-1}(\ker A)=B^{-1}(\operatorname{im}B\cap\ker A)\cong(\operatorname{im} B\cap\ker A)\oplus\ker B$. Thus, $$\dim\ker(AB)=\dim\ker B+\dim(\operatorname{im} B\cap\ker A)\\ \dim\ker(AB)-\dim\ker B=\dim(\operatorname{im} B\cap\ker A)$$

Apply this to $B=A^k$ to obtain the result.